# Django "TypeError: an integer is required" on form.save

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, upload, imagefield

I have a form with 11 fields and one image upload field. After filling in and hitting submit, I'm given a TypeError saying that an integer is required.  this error doesn't come up if i remove the imagefield.  checking the image directory, the files are saved to the server before the error is thrown.

Forms.py:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    seller_email = forms.EmailField(max_length="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "jsmith@stevens.edu"}))  
    title = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"The Cat in the Hat"}))
    edition = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"5"}))
    author = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"Dr. Seuss"}))
    isbn = forms.CharField(label="ISBN", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"9780717260591"}))
    price = forms.FloatField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':"number", 'placeholder':"50.00"}))
    classcode= forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"MA115"}))
    #description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea(attrs={'placeholder':"You should buy this because..."}))
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.Select(), choices=([(4,"New"), (3,"Good"), (2,"Fair"), (1,"Poor")]))
    seller_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"John Doe"}))
    seller_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':"(555) 555-1234"}))

    picture = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput('accept':"image/*"))
    #picture = forms.ImageField()
    uuid = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=uuid.uuid4())
    timeposted = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=datetime.now())
    sale_status = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=True)



    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('seller_email', 'title', 'edition', 'author', 'isbn', 'price', 'classcode', 'description', 'condition', 'seller_name', 'seller_phone', 'picture', 'uuid', 'timeposted', 'sale_status')
        #exclude = ("uuid", "timeposted", "sale_status", "picture", "school")
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from cbt.accounts.models import School, UserProfile
from cbt.listings.models import Listing
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.files import File
from datetime import datetime
from cbt.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from cbt.listings.forms import ListingForm

school_list = School.objects.all().order_by('name')

def add(request):

    form = ListingForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_multipart():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cbt.views.home'))      

    return render_to_response('listings/add.html', {'school_list':school_list, 'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the exact error code:

```
Environment:



Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://alligator.collegebooktrade.info/listings/add/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'cbt.accounts',
 'cbt.listings')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/cbt/cbt/listings/views.py" in add
  25.           form.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  364.                              fail_message, commit, construct=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  86.         instance.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1576.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  909.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  872.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  249.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  45.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  212.             os.chmod(full_path, settings.FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS)

Exception Type: TypeError at /listings/add/
Exception Value: an integer is required
```

EDIT:  As requested:

```
Model:
class Listing(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length="100")
edition = models.CharField(max_length="5")
author = models.CharField(max_length="50")
isbn = models.CharField(max_length="13")
price = models.FloatField()
classcode = models.CharField(max_length="12")
description = models.CharField(max_length="400")
condition = models.CharField(max_length="10")
#school = models.OneToOneField(School)
school = models.CharField(max_length="36")

picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="listings")

#CONTACT INFO:
seller_name = models.CharField(max_length="30")
seller_phone = models.CharField(max_length="11")
seller_email = models.EmailField(max_length="75")

uuid = models.CharField(max_length="36")
timeposted = models.DateTimeField()
sale_status = models.BooleanField() #0 for sale, 1 for sold
```

Settings.py:

```
#just including pertinent settings...
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS '0760'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS  ('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware')
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE  '2621440'
```

Comment: Have you properly set the upload_to attribute on your image field and does the directory exist with correct permissions?  That exception is almost certainly coming from whatever the value of settings.FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS is.  Including the configuration on your model and its fields would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your settings.py script, you have this line:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS '0760'
```

It should not have quotes around it. You are trying to call os.chmod() with a string as the second argument when it expects an integer. Specifically, the octal permissions value. In python, numbers with a leading 0 are automatically considered to be octal values and are converted to integers. So, just use this line instead:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0760
```

By the way, why aren't you using equals signs in your settings.py?

Comment: Thanks! i am, i copied it from the error page though so instead of equals signs, it used tabs to format

Answer (score 0):

Updated Solution to the above problem isjust add this snippet in your settings.py file.

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o760
```

Keep it in mind that you have to use `o` .